# phpunit fail message for wrong exception thrown

Tags: phpunit, message

I'm using phpunit for TDD approach. Currently, some tests I've already written fail, because I'm waiting for other people to catch up with my tests. Therefore, I want to print out a failed assertion message for each assertion that fails now, e.g.

```
$this->assertTrue($now_its_false, '> my friend should fix method X to return Y');
```

This works for standard assertions, but I can't figure out how to print such message when testing exceptions. For example, I've test a method that should raise an exception, but it doesn't. My code looks like this:

```
public function testSomethingIncorrect() {
  $this->setExpectedException('SomeException');
  $object->doSomethingThatShouldRaiseException();
  $this->fail('This call should raise exception!');
}
```

How to print out the test fail message here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "clear" way to achieve this. You can notice that `PHPUnit_Framework_Constraint_Exception` doesn't take any description argument.

Anyway you can do it "around".

```
try {
    $object->doSomethingThatShouldRaiseException();
    $this->fail('This call should raise exception!');
} catch ('SomeException') {

}
```